# Sortings pandas dataframe numbers first then strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns containing values like `P123Y8O9` mixture of numbers and characters and if I apply sort function to this particular series in dataframe, it sorts the strings basis first digit then second and so on, what I want is to sort the strings basis first all numbers like `32456789` and then mixed strings like `2AJ6JH67`

you can see that in above example numerically `2 (first digit of 2AJ6JH67)` comes before `3 (first digit of 32456789)` but the sorting is to be done `32456789` first and then `2AJ6JH67`

How to sort dataframes this way?

Comment: Can you add some 10 rows data sample with expected output?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to sort numeric and non-numeric data separately.

Below are equivalent examples for a `list` or `pd.Series`.

```
lst = ['P123Y8O9', '32456789']
lst_sorted = list(map(str, sorted(int(x) for x in lst if x.isdigit()))) + \
             sorted(x for x in lst if not x.isdigit())

# ['32456789', 'P123Y8O9']

s = pd.Series(lst)
s_sorted = pd.Series(list(map(str, sorted(int(x) for x in s if x.isdigit()))) + \
                     sorted(x for x in s if not x.isdigit()))

# 0    32456789
# 1    P123Y8O9
# dtype: object
```